# How to add Striped rows with Grid theme in jsPDF autotable?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I want to add striped rows with grid theme in jsPDF autotable. How we can set two themes or add css in table to get striped rows? I tried theme: 'grid','striped' so far. I didn't get any solution.

```
   var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
                doc.setFontSize(6);
                var elem = document.getElementById("table");
                var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
                doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
                    margin: {top: 100},
                    tableLineColor: [189, 195, 199],
                    tableLineWidth: 0.75,
                    bodyStyles: {lineColor: [189, 195, 199]},
                    theme: 'grid',
                    styles: {
                        fontSize: 8,
                        font: 'helvetica',
                        cellPadding: 2,
                        minCellHeight: 2,
                    },
                    columnStyles: {
                        0: {cellWidth: 35},
                        1: {cellWidth: 35},
                        2: {cellWidth: 185},
                        3: {cellWidth: 35},
                        4: {cellWidth: 35},
                        5: {cellWidth: 184},
                    },
                    headStyles: {
                        fillColor: [255, 255, 255],
                        textColor: [0, 0, 0],
                        fontSize: 8,
                        padding: 0,
                    },
                });
```

Comment: Hi @Daniyal, have a look at their documentation.  I have managed to style the rows by following their documentation here: https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable#styling-options.  Also take a look at their demos to see what it would look like here: https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable#styling-options.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the new html option instead you can use the `useCss` option to use css styles. You also have the alternateRow option for styling every other row. For more complex styles you can use the hooks.

Comment: Can you show me how i can do this because i didn't get any solution.